# Echo-ing unicode character

Tags: batch-file

I would like to echo the unicode character "é" in cmd via running bat file. I prepared a short script:

```
@echo off
SET message=Gép3
echo %message%
pause
```

how can I do that? Is there a possibility to put directly this letter into the code?

Comment: Press Alt + 232 on number pad number keys. Type `charmap` in Start Run dialog (Winkey + R). Select Dos Western Europe or whatever your region is. CMD use DOS character set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this (both are important):

- Use code page 65001 (UTF-8) `chcp 65001`
- When you save your .bat file, use UTF-8

i. e. edit your example code in this way:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
SET message=Gép3
echo %message%
pause
```

Again, it is important that you **save your .bat file with encoding UTF-8**

Comment: But that's unnecessary, and means it won't work on any other computer. Alt + 232 does what you want WITHOUT any changes to the environment.