# ╧, ╤ and ╪ show wrong on Windows 7 cmd console

Tags: cmd, windows-7

I have a python script that draws a table to the console output using the extended ASCII character codes 179-218, more specifically: 179(│), 185(╣), 186(║), 187(╗), 188(╝), 200(╚), 201(╔), 202(╩), 203(╦), 204(╠), 205(═), 206(╬), 207(╧), 209(╤) and 216(╪).

I run the script on both a Windows 10 and a Windows 7 machines. On the Windows 10 machine everything shows fine, but when I run it on the Windows 7 machine, it doesn't show the characters 209(╤), 207(╧) and 216(╪) properly. When I copy-paste the character to notepad and notepad++ it shows it right as well as typing these characters directly into other places works fine. The same happens when I type the character directly to the console, I get the wrong character. Here is what is shown:

[image]

What is the reason for this, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It's all about [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) (nothing to do with console font). E.g. `╧`  (U+2567 = _Box Drawings Up Single And Horizontal Double_) is encoded as 207 in extended ASCII (CP 437) however code 207 is `¤`  (U+00A4  _Currency Sign_)  in CP850 etc…

Comment: @Mofi, wow that's a lot of text. I didn't really get into all of it, but from your last comment I changed the font from "raster fonts" to "Lucidia Console" (the only other option is "consolas" which also works) and it fixed the issue. You can create an answer with this and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

1. The [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) used for [encoding the characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) in Python script is not the same as the code page used for the console by Windows command processor.
   The code page used by default by `cmd.exe` depends on region/country configured for the used account. The used code page for own user account can be seen by opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) and run the command `chcp`. Then it can be looked up on Wikipedia or other websites if this code page supports the characters not displayed correct at all.
2. The used console font does not support that code page respectively character encoding.

The following answers on Stack Overflow could be useful here to understand the issue:

- [Why are Danish characters not displayed as in text editor on executing batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052862/3074564)
- [Using another language (code page) in a batch file made for others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48982681/3074564)
- [Box drawing characters in batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58783563/3074564)

The default difference between console on Windows 7 and console on Windows 8/8.1/10 is the font used by default which cannot be changed from within a batch file using [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands).

So I suggest to compare the code page used by `cmd.exe` on Windows 7 and on Windows 10. On same code page used by both Windows according to configured country for the user account, I suggest to configure on Windows 7 font `Consolas` or `Lucida Console` instead of default **Raster Fonts** (`Terminal`) and check if that makes a difference.

For the font problematic see also:

- the TechRepublic quick tip [Add fonts to the Command Prompt](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/) and
- the old (2007) Microsoft Developer Blog
  [Why are console windows limited to Lucida Console and raster fonts?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070516-00/?p=26843)

By the way: On my Windows 7 machine the characters displayed on running a batch file started with a `*.lnk` file with **Raster Fonts 10x18** (*Selected Font - Terminal*) configured in properties of shortcut file really look like the characters of font `Terminal` while the characters displayed on running `cmd` look like the characters of `Courier New` although the properties of cmd console window show **Raster Fonts 8x12** (*Selected Font - Terminal*). I can see on just selecting **10x18** instead of **8x12** in **Size** in cmd properties that the look of the characters changes. So it looks like raster (bitmap) font `Terminal` does not support the default size **8x12** and therefore Windows uses `Courier New` as replacement to display the characters in default console window. The same behavior can be seen by me on my Windows XP machine. It is strange that Microsoft defined raster font `Terminal` as default font on Windows XP/Vista/7, but none of the `*.fon` files of this font supports the default font size **8x12** and so the replacement font `Courier New` is used to display the characters in default console window.